# Simplificar código de python

Tags: python

Buenas tengo un código y necesito hacerlo de la manera más simple posible. Este es el código, necesito hacerlo de una forma lo más básico posible(para una persona de primero de fp) pero no se me ocurre nada como mínimo tiene que hacer todo eso y tiene que tener alguna clase, y alguna def y luego ya con if y esas cosa básicas y usando términos básicos.

Si me podéis ayudar muchas gracias ah y el lenguaje es python

```
import random
import time

class bingo:
    _carton=[]
    _numerosRestantes=16
    _numerosBombo=[]
    _numerosSalido=[]
    _linea=False

    def __init__(self):
        self._carton=list(map(lambda x: str(x), random.sample(range(1, 100), 16)))
        self._origin=self._carton.copy()
        print (self._origin)
        self._numerosBombo=[i for i in range(1, 100)]

    def showCarton(self, origin=False):
        """
        Metodo que muestra el carton
        Si recibe origin=True, muestra el carton inicial
        """
        carton=self._origin if origin else self._carton

        for i in range(0, len(carton), 4):
            print(carton[i:i+4])

    def getNumeroBombo(self):
        """
        Metodo que devuelve un numero del bombo
        """
        numeroPos=random.randint(0, len(self._numerosBombo)-1)
        numero=self._numerosBombo[numeroPos]
        del self._numerosBombo[numeroPos]

        self._numerosSalido.append(numero)
        return numero
    #Busca en cartón, si esta = true (y pone X) , sino = false
    def marcarNumero(self, numeroMarcar):

        if numeroMarcar in self._carton:
            self._carton[self._carton.index(numeroMarcar)]="X"
            self._numerosRestantes-=1
            return True
        return False

    def isLinea(self):
        if self._linea==False and list(filter(lambda x: len(list(filter(lambda y: y=="X", x)))==4 ,[self._carton[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(self._carton), 4)])):
            self._linea=True
            return True
        return False

    def getNumerosSalido(self):
        """
        Metodo que devuelve los numeros que han salido en el bombo
        """
        return self._numerosSalido

    def getNumerosRestantes(self):
        """
        Metodo que devuelve la cantidad de numeros restantes para llenar nuestro carton
        """
        return self._numerosRestantes

bingo=bingo()
print("Este es tu carton!!!")
bingo.showCarton()

while bingo.getNumerosRestantes()>0:
    numeroBombo=str(bingo.getNumeroBombo())
    if bingo.marcarNumero(numeroBombo):
        print("---------------------------------------------")
        print("Tienes el numero:", numeroBombo, "/", len(bingo.getNumerosSalido()), ", te quedan:", bingo.getNumerosRestantes())
        bingo.showCarton()
        if bingo.isLinea():
            print("\n\n   ##### LINEA #####\n\n")
    else:
        print("han salido el numero:", numeroBombo, "/", len(bingo.getNumerosSalido()), ", te quedan:", bingo.getNumerosRestantes())

    time.sleep(1)

print("\n\n\n   ##### BINGO #####\n")
print("Este es tu carton inicial")
bingo.showCarton(True)
print("\nEstos son los", len(bingo.getNumerosSalido()), "numeros que han salido hasta completar el carton:", bingo.getNumerosSalido())
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenido! Nos dices que tienes una necesidad y luego muestras un código. No es claro si el código no funciona o qué problema tienes con él

Comment: Hola, Esta es mas una pregunta basada en opinión y no un error por solucionar que  es el objetivo de stackoverflow.  La respuesta seria inventa un ejercicio mas facil o explica cada método en una clase, luego enseña a declaras función para llamar al metodo si repetir codigo y luego enseña a declarar clases